# Circular, dependency in makefile. How can I solve it?

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a fairly simple makefile, but it crashes on linking all .o to build myprogram executable.

This is the error message:

```
make: Circular myprogram <- myprogram dependency dropped.
g++        -o .cpp
g++: no input files
make: *** [.cpp] Error 1
```

This is the makefile:

```
CODE = myprogram

OBJS = /home/Documents/Obj/object1.o /home/Documents/Obj/object2.o /home/Documents/Obj/object3.o /home/Documents/Obj/object4.o 

default: $(CODE)

C = g++ $(CXXFLAGS) -fopenmp -g

INCLUDE = -I/home/Documents/Include/

LIBS = -lfftw3 -lm $(LIB)

%.o: %.cpp
        $(C) $(INCLUDE)  -c -o $@ $<

$(CODE): $(OBJS) $(CODE).cpp
        $(C) $(INCLUDE) -o $(CODE) $(CODE).cpp $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

clean:
        - $(RM) $(CLEAN) $(CODE) $(OBJS)
```

Comment: That's not crashing. That's make giving you a warning and then `gcc` failing to run because you gave it no input. Are you sure this is the **exact** makefile you are using? You didn't change spacing or anything? That looks like you had `$(CODE): $(OBJS) $(CODE) .cpp` in your original file or perhaps had `CODE: myprogram # main binary` in the original makefile.

Comment: Seriously, I had `CODE = myprogram(blankspace)`.  What a dumb! Thanks ;)